# Is it possible to create array of variables in a python for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, variables

I am trying to play around the elements of a list.
For instance, I have a list like

```
list = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
```

Now I want to create a for loop and assign different words to different variables in the loop like...

```
word = ""
length = 0
for e in range(len(list)):
    word[e] = list[e]
    length[e] = len(list[e])
    print " The word '%s' and its length is %d " %(word[e], length[e])
```

I am now expecting the array of variables

```
word[1] = 'zone'
word[2] = 'abigail' .... and so on.
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Use `word = []; length = []` instead of `word = ""; length = 0`, use `word.append(list[e]); length.append(len(list[e]))` instead of `word[e] = list[e]; length[e] = len(list[e])`

Comment: You don't need `word`. It's just the initial list. And tip: do not name your variable `list`

Comment: You can already access your list like that so essentially you are just copying the list for no clear reason. If you want to make a list of word lengths, there are simpler ways to do that with a list comprehension.

Comment: You can iterate over a list with something like `for some_item in your_list:`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `word` is a `str` not a `list`. Don't try to index it! The same with `length`, it is an `int` variable!

You should use:

```
word = list[e]
length = len(list[e])
```

Also, avoid using `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in type.

**Edit:**

If you want all words in a list at the end you can use `list` variable declared at the start. If you want all the lengths stored in a list, change `lengths = 0` for `lengths = []` and append each length in the for loop (`lengths.append(len(list[e])`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a dictionary instead?

```
a_list = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
my_dict = {k: len(k) for k in a_list}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
for kk, vv in my_dict.iteritems():
    print("The word '{}' has lenght: {}".format(kk, vv))
```

If you want to concatenate the two longest words, then you can sort the dictionary by value, i.e.:

```
import operator
sorted_dict = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

And then concatenate the first results:

```
sorted_dict[0][0] + sorted_dict[1][0]
```

This results in:

```
>>> 'abigailtheta'
```

Granted, for that case I agree using lists results in a much simpler syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like this way. But now how can I access the word having higher length from the dictionary and then concatenating it with the next longer word.?

Comment: In the case of given list, the concatenated string should be 'abigailtheta'

Comment: In my way, 'abigail' is word[1] and 'theta' is word[2]. Now concatenation is very easy with word[1] + word [2]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a for loop

```
lst = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
word = lst[:] 
length = list(map(len, word))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But it ends with  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: That is because you have overwritten `list`... Try resetting your editor (if it's interactive), or make sure there is no variable named `list`.

Comment: @Madhu: You named your variable `list`, blocking access to the builtin type `list`.  That's why in this answer the variable is named `lst` instead.